How can you calculate whether the result is a decimal or a whole number in SQL?
I want to check whether the result is a decimal or an integer. So that it can be done in a manipulation or an existing function?
For example:
select case when a/b = integer then 1 when a/b = decimal then 2 end  from test


if a = 10 and b = 2 the result should be 1.
if a = 11 and b = 2 the result should be 2.

thanks.

Tag question with SQL implementation to get appropriate answer!

You can do this too
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN a % b = 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 2 
    END AS result
FROM 
    test;


THANKS BUT MOD NOT recognized built-in function name in client server sql..

@j-r23 you can use WHEN a % b = 0 THEN 1

You can use modulus function like this:
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN MOD(a, b) = 0 THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 
END AS ResultType
FROM test;

If MOD function is not available, you can use modulus operator
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN a % b = 0 THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 
END AS ResultType
FROM test;

And you can even use the FLOOR() function in the following way:
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN a / b = FLOOR(a / b) THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 
END AS ResultType
FROM test;


mod will not work in SQL

@AbdullaNilam That depends on which DBMS is being used, which was not tagged.

@Charlieface op missed. It's sql server

You could use the MOD function. It gives the remainder of a division.
MOD(a, b) will return zero if a is divisible by b.
MOD(a, b) will return a value greater than zero if a is not divisble by b, or in other words, a/b will not result in a whole number.

mod will not work in SQL

@AbdullaNilam Do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? I'm pretty sure I used MOD in SQL.

@AbdullaNilam SQL is a language which has its own differences on different DBMS . MOD will not work in SQL Server should be the correct way
